# Error during XPM Device Switch: remote certificate is invalid

Tags: experience-manager, web8.5, preview

I am using Web 8.5 with XPM installed.

It has two hotfixes:

- XPM_8.5.0.3571
- XPM_8.5.0.6084

Steps are as follows:

1. Click on Switch Device
2. Select a device other than desktop in device menu
3. Click "apply"

the result is this: [image]

The Stack Trace is this:

```
[AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.]

   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception) +2290757
```

Comment: Just a hunch, Frank, but does the same thing happen when you stay in desktop mode and press update preview?

Comment: Double check the following URLs are in https and valid certificates are present?
1. Web app URL
2. CMS URL
2. Preview Service URL

Comment: @Quirijn, when I stay in desktop mode and press "update preview", no issues.

Comment: Does the cert when inspected in browser have the exact "Issued to:" value as the presentation website hostname?  I had the same error when following these steps (switching to non-desktop view in XPM), error seems to go away after using a matching website name.  Incidentally, used openssl to generate new certificate as opposed to creating a self-signed cert in IIS.